# MySql, how can I group by, in a select query on positve or negative?

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by

I would like to group by all the the values which are negative and all those which are positive, any ideas how to do this ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

GROUP BY SIGN(field) should work.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN SomeColumn < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS negative_values,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SomeColumn >=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS non_negative_values
    FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 2):

Stefan's solution looks like the best answer so far.  If you would prefer for 0 to be grouped in with positive numbers, you can use

```
GROUP BY `field` >= 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
select count(*), IF(foo >= 0, "pos", "neg") as sign  from test group by sign;
```

where foo is the column with the positive or negative values

EDIT: Stefan's solution is more elegant and better if you want zero values treated differently from positive and negative ones.

Comment: I'd go for `>=` rather than `>` - zero is (IMHO) more naturally associated with positive than negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question was asked long ago, but it may help someone in the future.
NOTE: Below was tested in SQL server, I believe the same logic will apply in MySql.

```
    declare @temp table(
    id int,
    amount decimal(18,2),
    rate decimal(18,2),
    isPositiveAmount bit,
    isPositiveRate bit
)

insert into @temp values(1, 100.1, 12.3, null, null)
insert into @temp values(1, -1, -1, null, null)
insert into @temp values(2, 100.1, 12.32, null, null)

update @temp set isPositiveAmount = iif(amount >= 0, 1, 0), isPositiveRate = iif(rate >= 0, 1, 0)

select id, sum(amount), avg(rate), isPositiveAmount, isPositiveRate from @temp
group by id, isPositiveAmount, isPositiveRate
```